# Where to start off with networking

Tags: python, networking, network-programming

i want to start getting in depth with networking. where should I start? what should be the first steps.

Sorry if this question was already asked.

thank you

Comment: Please read ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: To me it seems a pretty normal question. If you don't want to answer it don't bother. This is a Q and A site. There's my question and I need answers.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to start reading:

[Python Network Programming](http://www.apress.com/9781430230038) or [Foundations of Python Network Programming](http://www.target.com/p/foundations-of-python-network-programming-paperback/-/A-12694339)

Comment: thanks brah, i'll look into these.

Answer (score 1):

This is depending on what you already know but I am a student and we started learning about networking using this book [The book](http://www.pearsonhighered.com/educator/academic/product/1,,0136079679,00.html)

Comment: i know really basic stuff. Not enough to understand how it all works tho. like i want to know the "why" and "how" behind all that.

thanks for the reply ;)

Comment: Then this book would be great I had a limited knowledge going in and using the book I know have a good understanding. No worries